# Join two tables on Power BI using same key in Table A

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm attempting to create multiple joins with two tables (Table A + Table B)  using the same key from Table A. The key on table A is "Name" and there are multiple columns in Table B that I need to join this with. Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go ahead and do it. Power BI allows multiple relations between tables, but only one of them will be "active": 
[Multiple Relationships Between Tables](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/multiple-relationships-between-tables-in-dax/)

To use inactive relations, you will have to refer to them in DAX using function called 
[USERELATIONSHIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/userelationship-function-dax)

Alternatively, you can replicate your table A as many times as you need, and setup regular relations. In my opinion, it's a better data model - it's more intuitive and easier to use.